# iBeacon not detected in demo application of SENSORO

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

I am trying to create an application that can detect beacons. I have purchased SENSORO beacons. I follow the instruction as per **[SENSORO iOS SDK guide](http://www.sensoro.com/en/developer#ios)**.

The thing is that it's not working, Yes of course I have cross verified with SENSORO app store application and guys the same device can able to detect three SENSORO iBeacons.

What is weird thing is even the same demo examples which are listed on website are also not working.

1. **[SBK Demo](https://github.com/Sensoro/SDK-iOS)**
2. **[Yunzi iOS](https://github.com/Sensoro/Yunzi-iOS)**

Above examples are guide to use SENSORO SDK for iOS.

I have tried with normal way of detecting iBeacons, still not able to succeed. Yes the app store application of SENSORO to configure iBeacon is able to identify beacons with the same device (**[SENSORO Beacon Utility](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sensoro-beacon-utility/id902437077?mt=8)**).

Is there any thing to do with the provisional profile? I am using provisional profile of my another project.

Code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SBKBeacon.h"
#import "SBKBeaconManager.h"
#import "SBKBeaconManager+Cloud.h"

@interface ViewController () <SBKBeaconManagerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) SBKBeaconID           *beaconID;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager     *locationManager;

@end

- (void)beaconManager:(SBKBeaconManager *)beaconManager didRangeNewBeacon:(SBKBeacon *)beacon {
    NSLog(@"Enter new beacon %@",beacon.beaconID.stringRepresentation);
    NSLog(@"%@",beacon.serialNumber);
    NSLog(@"%d",beacon.proximity);
    NSLog(@"%@",beacon.beaconID);
}

- (void)beaconManager:(SBKBeaconManager *)beaconManager beaconDidGone:(SBKBeacon *)beacon {
    NSLog(@"Leave a beacon %@",beacon.beaconID.stringRepresentation);
    NSLog(@"%@",beacon.serialNumber);
    NSLog(@"%d",beacon.proximity);
    NSLog(@"%@",beacon.beaconID);
}

- (void)beaconManager:(SBKBeaconManager *)beaconManager scanDidFinishWithBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons {

    NSLog(@"Scan finish...");
    NSLog(@"beacons :%@",beacons);
}          

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _beaconID = [SBKBeaconID beaconIDWithProximityUUID:SBKSensoroDefaultProximityUUID];
    [[SBKBeaconManager sharedInstance] startRangingBeaconsWithID:self.beaconID wakeUpApplication:YES];
    [[SBKBeaconManager sharedInstance] requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    [SBKBeaconManager sharedInstance].delegate = self;            
}
```

Comment: Just to check, the pop up requesting permission (resulting from requestAlwaysAuthorization) showed and you have agreed to it?

Comment: Yes, I did taken care of that and it was showing up.

Comment: I did some test on different devices and able to figure out that issue was with iOS device. I have iPhone 4S ( iOS Version 7.1 (11D167)), for this specific device beacons were not detected otherwise its perfect for iOS as well as Android devices.

Answer (score 0):

1: Check whether enable the background app refresh in Settings -> General ->Background App Refresh (In iOS 7 (7.0, 7.1 etc.), it is need)
2: Check whether enable the location service in Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services, and enable the authorization of this APP
3: Check whether enable the WiFi, even there not wifi signal.

If all above is enabled, but still not working, try to reset the network settings in Settings -> General -> Reset or reboot the device.